# How expensive are streams?

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

In Flutter i have a view with a slider containing a grid of many textfields. I plan to attach each textfield to its own stream (with a streambuilder) resulting in several hundred streams that are running simultanieously. My question is: Can this lead to problems in terms of performance?

Comment: You are showing several hundreds of textfields at the same time on a mobile app?
Streams are quite cheap but that depends on how exactly they are used. If you use them a lot, it can add up. Using Listenables like the Flutter framework does is notable cheaper but it's probably premature optimization in your case. Create the code and make benchmarks. There is no way around that if you really want to know.

Comment: I'm new too Flutter as well but I'm thinking some lazy load mechanism on the slider maybe using scrollview or something so you are not fetching the whole thing all at once.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer think of the view as like a lottery ticket. The view gets only updated if the user clicks a button (The mentioned textviews acts as the buttons too). Thanks a lot for your considerations anyway!

Comment: @rxlky Will definitely consider!

Answer (score 0):

Found your question while seeking the same answer ...

I've gone ahead and built what I needed which does open just a few dozen streams at once and I'm not seeing any performance issues at all.

[This video](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf) from Flutter says, "don't optimise prematurely - we do the optimisations for you - only optimise if you are seeing performance issues."
And I'm pretty sure that the most expensive operations are pretty much always the screen redraw ones, not memory and state management.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60210639/1290746),  `StreamBuilder` internally actually does the same thing as `setState`.

So - I didn't find an authoritative answer, but I did find info that says it should be fine,
**and** my own basic experiment also suggested that.