# Flutter Performance - SetState vs StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, which way has the more performance over high load handling?

Let's say that we are listening to a stream which emits around 1000 msgs per second. Which way will have more performance?

1) Using setState() like

```
stream.listen((msg) => setState(() => _msg = msg)
```

then in the build method

```
return Text(_msg);
```

2) Using stream builder

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data)
                  );
                }
              },
            )),
```

Comment: Can't you use profiling to find out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According with flutter docs:

> When setState() is called on a State, all descendent widgets will
>   rebuild. Therefore, localize the setState() call to the part of the
>   subtree whose UI actually needs to change. Avoid calling setState()
>   high up in the tree if the change is contained to a small part of the
>   tree.

Therefore in your particular case may you will haven't performance differences, however in large widget trees StreamBuilder will isolate your widget  avoiding rebuild in entire tree.

I also recommend you to check you specific scenario with "DevTools Widget Inspector Page". It will give you a real time analysis, including GPU time, memory consumption, performance and much more.

Comment: good to know it helped @KavindaJayakody. You will not regret to check the performance with DevTools, It will worth it efforts, performance never can be neglect!

Answer (score 4):

Both are identical (modulo the fact that `StreamBuilder` does it in a different `Widget`).

To begin with, `StreamBuilder` internally does that same `setState` call.

Comment: "StreamBuilder internally does that same setState call", only for widget it is under and not whole app widget tree?